# Find a group to which $A_4/V_{4}$ is isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-isomorphism

I have a question that states to find a familiar(fairly common) group that is isomorphic to $A_4/V_{4}$, where $V_{4}$ is the Klein-4 group.  I am probably just having a mental break, but either the answer or some guidance to get to a possible solution would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the order of $A_{4}/V_{4}$ is $12/4 = 3$. How many groups of order $3$ are there up to isomorphism? (Feel free to comment if you need more).

Comment: So would it be $\Z / 3 \Z$?

Comment: @BrandonKlein: indeed, the only group of order 3 up to isomorphism is the cyclic group of order $3$, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.